# Compilation unit has been modified

Tags: java, eclipse, dto

I created a DTO class and implemented the java serializable class. when I created auto generated uid, the above message was give. asking to save. what does this mean?

I did an internet search but could not find a suitable answer.

Comment: For future reference, you get that notification when you attempt to generate a serialVersionUID in Eclipse, for a class that has pending edits (aka, you haven't saved it yet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

serialVersionUID is used during serialization/de-serialization process.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html